# Persisting Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am new to the Spark world. How we can persist a Dataframe so that we can use it across the components.

I have a Kafka stream from which, I am producing the Dataframe through the Rdd.Tried RegisterAsTempTable ,but the table is not accessible in another program.

I want to access this Dataframe in another class through sqlContext and use the query result for further calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the contents of a DataFrame as a Parquet file and read the same in another program. you can register as Temp table in next program.Spark SQL provides support for both reading and writing Parquet files that automatically preserves the schema of the original data.

```
//First Program
dataframe.write.format("parquet").save("/tmp/xyz-dir/card.parquet")
//where /tmp/xyz-dir/ is a HDFS directory

//Second Program
val parquetRead = sqlContext.read.format("parquet").load("/tmp/xyz-dir/card.parquet")

//Parquet files can also be registered as tables and then used in SQL statements.
parquetRead.registerTempTable("parquettemptable")
val cust= sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM parquettemptable")

//After use of parquet file, delete the same in the second program
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://hostname:8030"), sc.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.delete(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/tmp/xyz-dir"),true) // isRecusrive= true
```

Comment: val cdrDF = rdd.map(PaymentProcessor.parseCallCreditCardRecord).toDF() \       when I tried cdrDF.saveAsParquetFile("datafile.parquet","/tmp/xyz-dir/") ,I am seeing Compiler Error.Can you please guide me if am missing something here.

Comment: @BindumaliniKK saveAsParquetFile Deprecated (Since version 1.4.0) Use write.parquet(path)  [see](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/sql-programming-guide.html) and [1.3 approach](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html), Arvind pls modify accordingly

Comment: I am facing exception: INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation - Listing file:/SparkSpace/PaymentCardFraudResearch/card.parquet on driver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No predefined schema found, and no Parquet data files or summary files found under file:/SparkSpace/PaymentCardFraudResearch/card.parquet.
 at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)

Comment: / Writing as :    cdrDF.write.parquet("card.parquet")                                Reading as : val parquetRead = sqlContext.read.parquet("card.parquet")

Comment: @ArvindKumar :Do we need to add any dependency : Because I am getting an Exception : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat .I am following the updated code snippet.

Comment: I think you should build the jar with dependencies. No action is required in Pom file.

Comment: @ArvindKumar : I am building the jar.But when I run the program I see java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormat
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)

Comment: Please check you pom.xml, refer https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/pom.xml. Add scala perspective to your project file.

Answer (score 2):

DataFrames can also be [saved](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#saving-to-persistent-tables) as persistent tables into Hive metastore using the **saveAsTable** command. Notice existing Hive deployment is not necessary to use this feature. Spark will create a default local Hive metastore (using Derby) for you. Unlike the createOrReplaceTempView command, saveAsTable will materialize the contents of the DataFrame and create a pointer to the data in the Hive metastore.

Persistent tables will still exist even after your Spark program has restarted, as long as you maintain your connection to the same metastore. A DataFrame for a persistent table can be created by calling the table method on a SparkSession with the name of the table.

By default saveAsTable will create a “managed table”, meaning that the location of the data will be controlled by the metastore. Managed tables will also have their data deleted automatically when a table is dropped.

Comment: I tried SaveAsTable("tablename") as well.But again ,got table not found exception when I tried to get the table in another program using sqlContext.

Comment: I got to know in one of the discussions that using hivecontext instead of sqlcontext will persist the table which can be accessed across the components.So I created the HiveContect and used the hiveContext.saveTable("table"). I don't know much about Hive.Would be a great help to guide me how we will be configuring meta store.

Comment: do you have hive installed already ? if already exists , you should have metastore already

Comment: No.Not installed.Just using this artifact :spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10

Comment: as per my above post , you need not have hive installed , spark will create local hive meta store for you,use saveAsTable and try to access again and let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: It throws me compilation error saying sqlContext must be used to store "temporary" tables.But when I use HiveContext, I get error again as its deprecated.